# Json Data from WCF services after calling and binding with parameter in web service(android client)

Tags: c#, json, api, wcf

[my web services are like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJMnP.jpg)

[i am using this web service by posting data using postman like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhiJd.jpg)

[Interface is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpLhz.jpg)

[Model is like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p31X4.jpg)

the debug pointer is hitting the method but not getting any data in web service.

Comment: you are supposed to send the model in the body instead of the url

Comment: Can you give any example.i am only using class library.

Comment: well as simple as deleting ?model=.............
in postman go to body, raw and put a valid json in there 
{
 username = "user",
password = "pass"
.....etc
}

Comment: no-one wants to see pictures of your code. Code is text, so paste it into the question as such (anyway it should be quicker than making image files!). Then it's searchable, and people can re-use parts of it as necessary for an answer. As a warning: questions which don't include actual code (not pictures) in the question can be closed as off-topic by the moderators.